# How can I automate writing contracts in MS Word using a form?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, forms

At my job, vendor contracts must be written for service work.  Many of the items on these contracts that must be filled out are repetitive data.  Is there a way to set up an electronic form to fill out these items without having to type them every time?

For instance, there are five areas that are contracted for service work. There could be a dropdown list that contains these five places, and on submitting the form, it will automatically place the wording in the proper place on the contract.

Another example is that one of the outline lines states "Total price including labor and materials shall not exceed (price)."  This amount could be entered on a form, and then have it output to the contract.

What is a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not 100% certain but look up Microsoft Word "Mail Merge" functionality and see if that will help you simplify this task some.

Comment: As @Spittin'IT said, I would use [Mail Merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3) for your first example, and [Fill-in fields](https://adamprescott.net/2013/07/12/fill-in-field-prompts-in-word-2013/) for the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments:

Start by using Use [Mail Merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3) for the first example.

Start by using [Fill-in fields](https://adamprescott.net/2013/07/12/fill-in-field-prompts-in-word-2013/) for the second example.